# how to findViewById for an icon in menu in adapter class

Tags: java, android

I just created menu like this as a Bottom Bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bb_menu_recents"
        android:icon="@drawable/floor"
        android:title="Floor 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/floorNumber"
        android:icon="@drawable/floor"
        android:title="Floor 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bb_menu_nearby"
        android:icon="@drawable/floor"
        android:title="Others" />
</menu>
```

and created also an getter and setter class,I have also created An adapter with an holder and this is my adapter class

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.R;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.getters_and_setters.BottomBarItem;

/**
 * Created by dell on 2/27/2017.
 */

public class CustomBottomBarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BottomBarItem> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<BottomBarItem> data = new ArrayList<BottomBarItem>();

    public CustomBottomBarAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<BottomBarItem>data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId,data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            floorRecordHolder floorHolder = null;

            if (row == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                floorHolder = new floorRecordHolder();
                floorHolder.floorNo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.floorNumber);

            }else {
                floorHolder = (CustomBottomBarAdapter.floorRecordHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            BottomBarItem bottomBarItem = data.get(position);
            floorHolder.floorNo.setText(bottomBarItem.getFloorNo());
            return row;
        }

        static class floorRecordHolder{
            TextView floorNo;
            ImageView floorImage;
        }
    }
```

This is Activity Code

I just want to set icon in the menu like I set text which is also in the menu like this

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.adapters.CustomBottomBarAdapter;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.fragments.TablesFragment;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.getters_and_setters.BottomBarItem;

public class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;
    CustomBottomBarAdapter customBottomBarAdapter;
    ArrayList<BottomBarItem> bottomBarArray = new ArrayList<BottomBarItem>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
        customBottomBarAdapter = new CustomBottomBarAdapter(this,R.menu.bottombar_menu,bottomBarArray);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         * Initializing the viewpager with fragments
         */
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        adapter.addFragment(new TablesFragment(), "Progress");
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Example1"), "Example1");
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Example2"), "Example2");
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Example3"), "Example3");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        //adding viewpager to the tablayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    }
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}

    floorHolder.floorNo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.floorNumber);
```

but for an icon not for textview if any thing unclear please just notify me sorry for bad english

Comment: Where do you have a MenuInflater for the bottom bar? I don't think ArrayAdapter is what you need here

Comment: I just created a Grid View like this with one item only and make this repeats as in the data base with a selects form,all I need I want to create a bottom bar like I created a grid view, I just did like in the Grid View by creating a getter and setter class and an adapter class @cricket_007

Comment: I see no grid view in your question. You have a menu XML, and you load that with a MenuInflater... You set the text and icon from a MenuInflater, not an ArrayAdapter

Comment: yeah exactly my question is in bottom bar not in grid view but i need to do something like i did in grid view you got what i want exactly? @cricket_007

Comment: I think you mean just change the extension with MenuInflator instead of ArrayAdapter? ,I need just a sample adapter class for bottom bar if you could@cricket_007

Comment: Please show the Activity code where you think that Adapter should be loaded. I'm sorry, your question is very unclear because a `menu.xml` file simply cannot be loaded within an ArrayAdpapter

Comment: Ok I gonna post the Activity code now @cricket_007

Comment: Check now the Activity I posted @cricket_007

Comment: I have not used that BottomBar library... I assumed you were just using the built-in Android Support one. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: You cannot set the icon. Read here. https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to set icon in the menu like I set text

Where exactly are you setting the Text? This adapter isn't being used...

```
customBottomBarAdapter = new CustomBottomBarAdapter(this,R.menu.bottombar_menu,bottomBarArray);
```

You actually are setting the text with this...

```
mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
```

Basically, `R.menu` resources aren't to be loaded into a `ArrayAdapter`, generally, only `R.layout` values are.

---

In your activity, you would need something like this

```
mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
BottomBarTab tab = mBottomBar.getTabWithId(R.id.floorNumber);
mBottomBar.setIconResId(R.drawable.new_img); // This method doesn't work, though
```

As I commented, that wouldn't work because that method isn't public (and actually doesn't update the icon at all).

There is an open issue for it.

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/659

---

Overall, you seem to have a `TabLayout` for the "horizontal" views, so I would use that instead of it **and** a `BottomBar`.

You actually can very easily set the icons of a `TabLayout`.

OR use the actual Android Support [`BottomNavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html), which again, has the ability to change the icons.

Comment: Thanks alot @cricket_007 it's very useful tutorial